# Comparison in text file using Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, qtextedit

I am beginner in UI design using Qt. My project now is doing comparison. For example: if I have 2 text file.

[image]

How can I compare the number line by line? Because I have so many text file like this, and I need compare them on by one.What I can do now is only read the text file by line order. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JLev Hi, actually I have no idea about that, I can use textEdit to read the text file by line now.

Comment: So, your actual question is how to compare two strings?

Comment: If you have a very precise format in your files (like : 1 integer on each line). You could create a data structure like QVector<int> and implement a comparison of two vectors. Do you want to show the comparison to the user or just some results ? Like a diff tool, or just a report ?

Comment: @ymoreau Hi, yes, actually there are 11 float number like 0.002 in each line. After comparison, I want to list them by order, for example the text file who has the greater difference between each line, will put it in front of another one.

Comment: @jycjo then it has nothing to do with GUI right ? You just want an algorithm ? You don't even need Qt for that I think, depending on your needs. Just create a data structure for each file that contains your floats, create a class that keeps the filename and the float-list together, and implements the comparison algorithm you want (average of diff, sum of diff ? whatever) in a function. Then you can sort your objects in another data structure and display them (check QListView and QListModel).

Comment: @ymoreau yup, you are correct. But I am not good at C++ programming, every step I have learnt is from the actual example.Qt for me is a reinforcement to complete the UI design.So how can I create a data structure

Comment: @ymoreau, there is no point of using `QVector<QString>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is simple

1. Read both files (always make sure they are opened successfully)
2. Read files line by line and convert strings to numbers for comparison.
3. Quit if there is no data left.

Moreover, you need to make sure that the format of files is consistent otherwise, you need to make sure what you manipulate is a real number. I assume numbers are integers but of course you can change it. Extra precautions are required in this kind of project. I will leave it to you. The simplified code for the above procedure is

```
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>


int main()
{
    QFile data1("text1.txt");
    if (!data1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug() << "text1.txt file can't be opened...";
        return -1;
    }

    QFile data2("text2.txt");
    if (!data2.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug() << "text2.txt file can't be opened...";
        return -1;
    }


    QTextStream in1(&data1), in2(&data2);

    while ( !in1.atEnd() && !in2.atEnd() ) {
        QString num1 = in1.readLine();
        QString num2 = in2.readLine();
        if ( num1.toInt() > num2.toInt() )
            qDebug() << num1.toInt() << ">" << num2.toInt(); 

        // do the rest of comparison
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now in my case, the txt files are

text1.txt

```
1
2
3
4
```

text2.txt

```
3
5
1
6
```

The output is

```
3 > 1
```

---

Edit: the OP is looking for the difference and its sum.

```
int sum(0);
while ( !in1.atEnd() && !in2.atEnd() ) {
    QString num1 = in1.readLine();
    QString num2 = in2.readLine();
    int result = num1.toInt() - num2.toInt();
    qDebug() << num1.toInt() << "-" << num2.toInt() << " = " << result;
    sum += result;
 }
 qDebug() << "sum = " << sum;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, although I want to create an array to compare them one by one, but this answer shows me a way to do my project, thanks a lot again.

Comment: sorry ,you know how to create an array to compare them line by line?

Comment: Why do you need array?!

Comment: sorry, I think wrongly. But If I need the result of the difference between them in each line? how can I get it?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You already have the comparison for each line.

Comment: For your example, if I need the result of difference of line one which is (1-3) and line 2 for (2-5) and line 3 for (3-1) and so on, after that I need the sum of all the result.

Answer (score 0):

Basic approach would be something like this:

```
  QString filename1("C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/t1.txt");
  QString filename2("C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/t2.txt");

  QFile file(filename1);
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  QTextStream in(&file);
  QStringList textOfFile1;
  while (!in.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    textOfFile1.append(line);
  }

  QFile file2(filename2);
  file2.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  QTextStream in2(&file2);
  QStringList textOfFile2;
  while (!in.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    textOfFile2.append(line);
  }

  if(textOfFile1.size() != textOfFile2) return false;
  for(int i = 0; i < textOfFile1.size(); i++)
  {
      if(textOfFile1[i] != textOfFile2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
```

i.e. You read the files into a QStringList and you compare the lists line by line. This way you can also catch the firs # of line where there was a mismatch. Note that such comparison also considers white spaces such as \n \t etc.

PS: wrap the readers into functions, to avoid duplication like me. :)

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: thanks for your helping, actually I want to know which one is greater, for my example,the first file is greater than the second one since 2 > 1, 4=4, 8>8. I can promise that every file is not the same.

Comment: 1) Remove the whitespaces from the string using the `str.simplified();` function. Then you simply convert the string to float. Like `myvar.toFloat()` [QString Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) Then you can compare them :) If it helped please accept my asnwer. Thanks!